# How can we change the colour of the log4j messages displayed in the JFace TableViewer

Tags: java, log4j, swt, jface

I am displaying the log4j messages on the TableViewer created but now I want to change color of the messages based on the info,debug, warning, error messages. How can this be done? The code to fetch the messages into table viewer is as follows:

```
TableViewerColumn message = new TableViewerColumn(viewer, SWT.NONE);
        message.getColumn().setWidth(800);
        message.getColumn().setText("Message");
        message.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider()
        {
            @Override
            public void update(ViewerCell cell)
            {
                Object element = cell.getElement();
                if(element instanceof MyObject)
                {
                    MyObject obj = (MyObject) element;

                    cell.setText(obj.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private static class MyObject
    {
        private String first;
        private String second;
        private String message;

        public MyObject(String first, String second,String message)
        {
            this.first = first;
            this.second = second;
            this.message = message;
        }

        public String getFirst()
        {
            return first;
        }

        public void setFirst(String first)
        {
            this.first = first;
        }

        public String getSecond()
        {
            return second;
        }

        public void setSecond(String message)
        {
            this.second = second;
        }

        public String getMessage()
        {
            return message;
        }

        public void setMessage(String message)
        {
            this.message = message;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `ViewerCell.setBackground` and `ViewerCell.setForeground` to set the background and foreground colors of cells in your `update` method.

Alternatively instead of overriding the `update` method of `ColumnLabelProver` you can override the `getText`, `getBackground` and `getForeground` methods.